# Accordion table an js

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

I have this code that allows me to get data from the sql database.

Code Table:

```
<table id="id_tabella" class="fold-table" align="center">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th style="">Id</th>
                                <th>OrderCode</th>
                                <th>Partner</th>
                                <th>NrProdotti</th>
                                <th>Totale</th>
                                <th>Stato</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
              <?php
                  while( $result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($run_query,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                if($result) {
               ?>
                              <tr id="<?php echo $result['Id']; ?>" class="view">
                              <td style=""><?php echo $result['Id']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $result['OrderCode']; ?></td>
                                <td><img  align="middle" src="<?php echo $result['Img']?>" width="10%"></td>
                                <td><?php echo $result['NrProdotti']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $result['TotaleOrdine']; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <form method="POST" action="">
                                        <input name = "idOrdine" value="<?php echo $result['Id'] ?>" type="submit">
                                  </form>
                               </td>
                              </tr>
              <tr class="fold">
                                <td colspan="6">
                                    <div class="fold-content">
                                        <h3>DETTAGLIO ORDINE</h3>
                                        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
                                         <table>
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Dettaglio Ordine:</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td>
                                               <?php
                                               $data = json_decode($result['JsonOrdine'], true);
                                               foreach($data['products'] as $key=>$val){
                                                    echo '<b>'.$val['name'].' * '.$val['quantity'].'</b><br>';
                                                    foreach($val['attributes'] as $keys=>$value){
                                                            echo $value['name'].' * '.$value['quantity'].'<br>';
                                                    }
                                               }
                                               ?>
                                            </td>
                  </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                         </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr><?php } } sqlsrv_free_stmt($run_query);?>
                            </tbody>
```

I can't get the js script at the bottom of the page to work with the code:

```
alert(ultimo);
```

Code JS:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(newNoti, 5000);
            function newNoti(){
          //var ultimo = $('#id_tabella tr').last().attr("Id");
          var ultimo = $('#id_tabella tr').last().attr("Id");
          alert(ultimo);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "o_accoda.php",
                    data: {'last_id': ultimo},
                    success:function(resp){
                                if(resp != ""){
                                    $("#audio")[0].play();
                                    $('#c_id_tabella').append(resp);
                                    var rowCount = $('#c_id_tabella').find('tr').length-1;

                    //$("#id_tabella").append(resp);
                    //var rowCount = $('#id_tabella').find('tr').length-1;
                                    $('#demo').html("ORDINI IN ARRIVO: " + rowCount);
                                }
                            },
                    error:function(){
                            alert('Some problem occured, please try again.');
                            }
                })
            }
        });
    </script>
```

it returns me "undefined"

Comment: You always ends with TR element: <tr class="fold">. This element doesn't have any id attribute. Check your while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've converted you PHP to HTML just for testing.

Check this Code snippet. I've selected row you are getting with red.

But the correct row must be found with:
`$('#id_tabella tr.view').last()`

```js
var lastRow = $('#id_tabella tr').last();
lastRow.css('background','red'); // TEST which row we found

var ultimo = lastRow.attr("Id");
console.log(ultimo);

// Now make a correction
lastRow = $('#id_tabella tr.view').last();
ultimo = lastRow.attr("Id");
console.log(ultimo); // Now Good!
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="id_tabella" class="fold-table" align="center" style="margin-bottom:40px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="">Id</th>
      <th>OrderCode</th>
      <th>Partner</th>
      <th>NrProdotti</th>
      <th>Totale</th>
      <th>Stato</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="id1" class="view">
      <td style="">id1</td>
      <td>OrderCode</td>
      <td><img align="middle" src="#" width="10%"></td>
      <td>NrProdotti</td>
      <td>TotaleOrdine</td>
      <td>
        <form method="POST" action="">
          <input name="idOrdine" value="id1" type="submit">
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fold">
      <td colspan="6">
        <div class="fold-content">
          <h3>DETTAGLIO ORDINE</h3>
          <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Dettaglio Ordine:</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>XXX
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

So in your code you found "last" row that is actually this one:

```
<td>
                                               <?php
                                               $data = json_decode($result['JsonOrdine'], true);
                                               foreach($data['products'] as $key=>$val){
                                                    echo '<b>'.$val['name'].' * '.$val['quantity'].'</b><br>';
                                                    foreach($val['attributes'] as $keys=>$value){
                                                            echo $value['name'].' * '.$value['quantity'].'<br>';
                                                    }
                                               }
                                               ?>
                                            </td>
```

So try changing your search to:

```
var ultimo = $('#id_tabella tr.view').last().attr("Id");
```